# Add extension to all files within a directory that contain exact string

Tags: files, scripting, rename, search

I have a large directory with multiple levels and tons of files. A majority (but not all) of these files are HTML files, but do not have the `.html` extension (a problem when copying over to Windows).

All of the HTML files have this as a **first** line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

How can I, by just using a command, add the `.html` extension on to all files containing this string?

I have seen this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108527/recursively-add-file-extension-to-all-files), but it does not rename based on whether the containings a string.

Comment: You could easily write a perl or shell script to do this. What shell are you using?

Comment: What is the expected format of the filenames without the `.html` extension.  Is it possible they may have a dot `.` elsewhere in their name?

Comment: @Peschke I am using the bash shell on Ubuntu.

Comment: @MikeD I cannot be sure of the extensions or names of other files. Some files will have dots in their names (some end with `.jpg`, for example), while others will be extensionless (on purpose, and are not HTML files). The only thing I can use to rename files is the fact that they all have the HTML header in their first line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all of the non-extension `.html` files have no extension at all, here is a simple bash script to accomplish what you need.

```
find . -type f ! -iname "*.html" -a ! -iname "*.htm" | while IFS= read -r file; do
    head -1 "${file}" | if grep -q '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">' ; then 
        mv "${file}" "${file}.html" 
    fi
done
```

This script does the following, in order:

1. Recursively finds all files in your current directory and child directories that do not have the `.html` extension.
2. Checks to see if the found files first line is the string you provided.
3. If the first line matches, the file is renamed to include the `.html` extension.

Comment: "Assuming all of the non-extension `.html` files have no extension at all": while all HTML files do not have extensions, some files (such as images or CSS files) **do** have extensions. Will this cause a problem when using your script?

Comment: @idempotence: Only files without an extension and start with the `<!DOCTYPE html ...` line you provided will be affected. As long as the other files do not start with that line, they will not be renamed. I recommend running this script on a subset of files first as a test.

Comment: Amazing! This script worked in exactly the manner I had wished. Thanks so much!

Comment: Perfect! You are very welcome. Glad to help. :)

Comment: I came up with something similar. Maybe use `-iname` in the `find`?  Also, if it's possible to see `.htm` extensions, as well, you may want to update the `find` as `find . -type f ! -iname "*.html" -a ! -iname "*.htm"`

Comment: @MikeD: Two great suggestions. I will edit the answer now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
goldn='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">' \
find . -type f \
   ! -name  '*.[hH][tT][mM]'     \
   ! -name '.*.[hH][tT][mM]'     \
   ! -name  '*.[hH][tT][mM][lL]' \
   ! -name '.*.[hH][tT][mM][lL]' \
-exec sh -c '
   shift "$1"
   while case $# in 0 ) break;; esac
   do
      read l1 < $1
      case $l1 in "$goldn" ) mv "$1" "$1.html";; esac
      shift
   done
' 2 1 {} +
```